# Insert icon in a sentence with a description below

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an icon with a text below in the middle of a sentence. I've searched and I've reached a similar result to what I'm looking for but not exactly: the sentence is in line with the text below the icon. I would like to have the sentence at the same level to the icon, and the text below the icon a little bit lower than all. My code is:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="display: block;">
The icon
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div style="display: block;">
        <i class="fa fa-paw"></i>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block;">
        BELOW
    </div>
</div>
has a text below
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it by using flexbox and change the flex-direction on the div that contains the icon and the text below to column. I don't know if it's what you want but I hope this will help:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="display: flex;">
The icon
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center">
        <i class="fa fa-paw"></i>
        <div style="display: block;">
           BELOW
        </div>
   </div>
has a text below
</div>
```